# Android user-set Locale always get reset after onCreate?

Tags: android, configuration, locale

I want to have a configurable language settings in my app.

So, in onCreate of my activity, I call Resources.updateConfiguration
with the new locale.

However, after onCreate (at some time, I can't find it when), the
locale is set back to the default locale.

On the code example below, the strings shown in the main layout (as
inflated by setContentView) shows the
"in" language version, BUT when I press the menu button, on which
onCreateMenu is called, the strings is
taken from the "en" (default) locale.

The log shows this:

```
 18337               oncreate  D  { scale=1.0 imsi=525/1 loc=intouch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=1 layout=34 uiMode=17 seq=143}
 30430        ActivityManager  I  Displayed activity yuku.coba.locale/.CobaLocaleActivity: 266 ms (total 266 ms)
 18337        KeyCharacterMap  W  No keyboard for id 65540
 18337        KeyCharacterMap  W  Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
 18337                 onmenu  D  { scale=1.0 imsi=525/1 loc=en_GB touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=1 layout=34 uiMode=17 seq=143}
```

Between "oncreate" and "onmenu", the locale magically changes.

Please help, I have been tinkering with this with no luck.

Code snippet:

```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       Configuration c = new Configuration();
       c.locale = new Locale("in");
       getResources().updateConfiguration(c, null);

       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       Log.d("oncreate", getResources().getConfiguration().toString());
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       Log.d("onmenu", getResources().getConfiguration().toString());
       new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.utama, menu);

       return true;
   }
```

Comment: This problem doesn't seem to appear on 1.5 emulator, but happens on 2.2 Nexus One.

Comment: Hi, I have the same proble. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every 100ms reset the Configuration :)

Comment: Thanks. What I do now is reset after 200 ms and reset after 400 ms. After that no need to reset again. It seems to work :D

Comment: Great :) I still have one problem on my Nexus - if I change the orientation to landscape, my app doesn't change the layout to the layout I have in layout-land folder. Do you have the same problem?

Comment: The problem with orientation was my stupid mistake - for testing purposes I put android:configChanges="orientation|locale|etc..." in the manifest, and fergot about it.

Comment: fhucho, one more thing we need to do is onConfigurationChange, the locale seem to be reset to the default. Make sure to force it back.

Answer (score 0):

I advice not force locale to something that is different from the device setting. You will run into the problems. You can move your call to onResume. It will be better, but still you're gonna fight device configuration. Again. Don't do this .

Comment: One case is because my app contains Indonesian language, a language that is currently not available on most phones. Still, a lot of Indonesians want the application in their own language, although the phone itself doesn't support that.

Comment: I do understand the case. Unfortunately, in my experience, it doesn't work very well. I've tried to do the same some time ago, but basically gave up because of all weirdness it caused.

Comment: Thanks, but for now I did what fhucho said, and it seems to be OK (tried in emulator 1.5, 1.6, 2.1 and my mobile 2.2). Maybe it will get some wierdness if I was using it for more complex application, but for now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of
getResources().updateConfiguration(c, null);

try
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(c, null);

(not getDefaultContext sorry)

Comment: They refer to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method I wrote, to handle this situation:

```
/**
     * Sets app language locale also taking account system resets of the Locale; Resetting of the Locale is done right after onResume of the first Activity that is run in the application.
     * So... if the AppLanugage is set e.g. in first activitys onCreate method, this language will be reset shortly after; To counter this the method starts the Timer (if a flag is set) to
     * handle pottential Locale resets that are done by the system.
     * 
     * In case the flag alsoReloadAfterDelay is set, usually the numberOfResetsOsDoes parameter and the numberOfResetsOsDoes should be used separately from eachother; Either the timer
     * shoudl run till the numberOfResetsOsDoes is matched, or run till the timer runs out of time, irrespectively of the number of resets the os does
     * @param appContext    The application context
     * @param lang  New language to set the locale
     * @param alsoReloadAfterDelay  The flag that says whether to start a timer that will handle pottential Locale resets, that are done by Android OS;
     * @param numberOfResetsOsDoes  The number of resets the OS does after onResume method of the first activity; So far I noticed that it is happening twice (emulator 2.3.3)
     * @param resetTimerDuration    The duration of the reset timer;
     * @see <a href="https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/android-developers/VEAWMCdyIWg">https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/android-developers/VEAWMCdyIWg</a> 
     * @return  True if the operation succeded (if the given lang param was appliable for instance); False otherwise
     */
    public static boolean setAppLanguageLocale(final Context appContext, final String lang, boolean alsoReloadAfterDelay, final int numberOfResetsOsDoes, int resetTimerDuration)
    {       
        final String previousAppLanguage = getAppLanguage(appContext);
        final String newLang = lang.toUpperCase(Locale.US);

        if(previousAppLanguage.equals(newLang))
            return true;

        setAppLanguageLocaleP(appContext, lang);

        if(alsoReloadAfterDelay)
        {               
            new CancellableCountDownTimer(resetTimerDuration, 10)
            {
                private int aResetCounter = 0;

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
                {
                    if(aResetCounter == numberOfResetsOsDoes)
                    {
                        this.cancel();
                        return;
                    }

                    String currentAppLanguage = getAppLanguage(appContext);

                    if(!currentAppLanguage.equals(newLang))
                    {
                        aResetCounter++;

                        setAppLanguageLocale(appContext, lang);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish()
                {                   
                }
            }.start();
        }

        return true;
    }
```