# Force "locale" in application

Tags: android, locale

I want to rotate my phone and keep the locale. I have folders values, values-**en** and values-**hr**. In every activity I have

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|locale"
```

and in every **activity.java** file I have

```
private Locale locale = null;

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (locale != null)
    {
        newConfig.locale = locale;
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

and in onCreate

```
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);               
    Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();

    String lang = settings.getString("language","en");
    if (! "".equals(lang) && ! config.locale.getLanguage().equals(lang))
    {
        locale = new Locale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
```

It works till I rotate my phone - app is still working, buttons and everything is fine - but locale is getting weird - sometimes it's my locale (hr) sometimes it's (en)...

What else I need to add?

Comment: Why are you messing with the locale, as opposed to letting the android system handle it for you?

Comment: I believe this may be a duplicate question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711712/android-user-set-locale-always-get-reset-after-oncreate, Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Please take a look at my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9535374/498067 .
It is very easy and doesn't require any changes in your Activities.

Comment: Aren't you forgetting to reset the contentView e.g setContentView(R.layout.mylayout)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply removed "if's" and everything is working now. Yes, it is a little "bulky" every time to "re-force" a locale but I couldn't find another way.

My solution is a little bit different, I just "re-force" it on onCreate and onConfigChange - not every 100ms or so and on Desire (2.2) it's working flawlessly.

**@Austyn**

Yes, it's pretty much the same question but I though is there another solution except "100ms forcing".

**@Mayra**

Users wanna have their mother-tongue (HR) but it's **not supported** in (current) mobile phones so this is the only way - to force it =/